# Superset Computing 90th percentile response time

Tags: sql, presto, apache-superset

Is there a way to get a line chart where I can display the 90th percentile response time from presto hour-wise?
The only available metric that is somewhat close to 90th percentile is average and it's not very wise to use that in analytics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is [Trino (formerly PrestoSQL)](https://trino.io), you can use the [`approx_percentile(value, 0.90)`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#approx_percentile) function along with `group by` on [`date_trunc('hour', dateTimeCol)`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_trunc).